# C++ How to convert a big integer in std::string form to byte/char-array/vector

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, byte, biginteger

I'm currently using a [BigInt library](https://faheel.github.io/BigInt/) that seems pretty useful so far.

But I'd like to store the computational result into a binary file for later use.

For reasons (binary schema, file size, etc), just storing the string is not an option.

The actual value must be stored to be read later on.

Example code of what I'm looking for:

```
BigInt example = BigInt("4");  
std::vector<uint8_t> bytes = to_bytes(example);
```

Examples of wanted result:

> "4" ---> [0000 0100] //BigInt("4");
> "255" --> [1111 1111] //BigInt("256");
> "542" --> [0000 0010] [0001 1110] //...
> "123456" --> [0000 0001] [1110 0010] [0100 0000]
> "absurdly high number" --> [?] [?] [?] [?] ... [n-bytes]

But also the inverse of course:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> bytes = readbytes(file, n-bytes);//already have this  
BigInt result = from_bytes(bytes);
```

So basically, I need `to_bytes()` and `from_bytes()` functions.

I'm using C++20.
Values are all positives but both solutions are welcome.

Comment: For up to 8 bytes, you can convert a number in string format to binary using `std::stoi()`, `std::stol()`, and `std::stoll()`.  To convert a number in binary format to a string, there is `std::to_string()`. For higher byte counts, that is where things get tricky, you will have to start parsing strings and manipulating binary bits manually. What you are really looking for is base10-to-base2 and base2-to-base10 conversions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau First of all, thanks for the question formatting and the quick respond comment. I have seen the std::stoll function being used in the library, but only for int, long, long long datatypes. stol will throw a out of range exception if bigger than 8 bytes if i'm not mistaken, I'm looking for a solution for cases larger than 8 bytes.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of a BigInt library that didn't have this capability built in.

Comment: @Eli: How do you want to encode negative numbers in binary? 2's complement?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas oh yea I'm using uint8. So no negatives here.

Comment: @Eli: "*oh yea I'm using uint8. So no negatives here.*" That doesn't follow. Are you saying that you're assuming all of the `BigInt` objects your function will get are positive? Or are you saying that the bytes in the encoded form are unsigned? Because those are two different statements.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas hey yea, doesn't follow indeed. I meant I'm only using positive numbers in BigInt. (it's late here my bad..)

Comment: This particular library uses `std::string` as internal representation of the value. I can't see how this can be efficient. As @MarkRansom suggested earlier, another implementation that uses, for example, a vector of 64-bit values to store the value might already have your desired binary dump, or it would be trivial to add.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to find a big-integer library that has this functionality built-in. This library doesn't even have shift operator support. So you're going to have to do a bunch of things that are probably extremely slow (especially considering that the library [does big-integer math *on strings*](https://github.com/faheel/BigInt/issues/24)) and much slower than if it gave you a decent interface.

To convert such a big integer to a series of bytes, you have to repeatedly extract each byte of data individually. A "byte" here being every 2<sup>8</sup> numbers. Without bitshift operators, it's going to involve a *lot* of divisions and modulo operations.

```
std::uint8_t extract_one_byte(BigInt &extract)
{
  auto intermediate = (extract % 256).to_int(); //Will always return a value on the range [0, 255]
  std::uint8_t the_byte = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(intermediate);
  extract /= 256;
  return the_byte;
}

std::vector<std::uint8_t> to_bytes(const BigInt &source)
{
  std::vector<std::uint8_t> ret;
  //ret.reserve(#); //pick a decent amount to reserve.
  BigInt curr = source;
  do
  {
    ret.push_back(extract_byte(curr));
  } while(curr != 0);

  return ret;
}
```

Note that this extracts the bytes in little-endian order (least-significant first). If you need big-endian, then you'll have to `std::reverse` the `vector` after construction. Building the vector backwards involves way more copying of data.

Going back is basically doing the reverse (from little-endian):

```
BigInt from_bytes(const std::vector<std::uint8_t> &le_bytes)
{
  BigInt ret = 0;
  for(auto curr_byte : le_bytes)
  {
    ret *= 256;
    ret += curr_byte;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it was using string as representation, performance is also key here. Do you know of a BigInt header only library? I wanted to use GMP, but i was having a compile nightmare and other stuff that shoudn't happen.

Comment: Or a bigint library you would recommend for this operation?

Comment: GMP would be my recommendation to try next. If you are having problems compiling it then post a question about that.